# How do I test if a method is called on particular objects pulled from the DB in Rails with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

If I have a `User` model that includes a method `dangerous_action` and somewhere I have code that calls the method on a specific subset of users in the database like this:

```
class UserDanger
  def perform_dangerous_action
    User.where.not(name: "Fred").each(&:dangerous_action)
  end
end
```

how do I test with RSpec whether it's calling that method on the correct users, without actually calling the method?

I've tried this:

```
it "does the dangerous thing, but not on Fred" do
  allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:dangerous_action).and_return(nil)
  u1 = FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "Jill")
  u2 = FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "Fred")
  UserDanger.perform_dangerous_action
  expect(u1).to have_recieved(:dangerous_action)
  expect(u2).not_to have_recieved(:dangerous_action)
end
```

but, of course, the error is that the User object doesn't respond to `has_recieved?` because it's not a double because it's an object pulled from the database.

I think I could make this work by monkey-patching the `dangerous_action` method and making it write to a global variable, then check the value of the global variable at the end of the test, but I think that would be a really ugly way to do it. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that I'm really trying to test two aspects of the `perform_dangerous_action` method. The first is the scoping of the database fetch, and the second is that it calls the correct method on the User objects that come up.

For testing the scoping of the DB fetch, I should really just make a scope in the `User` class:

```
scope :not_fred, -> { where.not(name: "Fred") }
```

which can be easily tested with a separate test.

Then the `perform_dangerous_action` method becomes

```
def perform_dangerous_action
  User.not_fred.each(&:dangerous_action)
end
```

and the test to check it calls the right method for `not_fred` users is

```
it "does the dangerous thing" do
  user_double = instance_double(User)
  expect(user_double).to receive(:dangerous_action)
  allow(User).to receive(:not_fred).and_return([user_double])
  UserDanger.perform_dangerous_action
end
```

Answer (score 1):

i think, in many cases, you don't want to separate a `where` or `where.not` into a scope, in that cases, you could stub ActiveRecord::Relation itself, such as:

```rb
# default call_original for all normal `where`
allow_any_instance_of(ActiveRecord::Relation)
.to receive(:where).and_call_original

# stub special `where`
allow_any_instance_of(ActiveRecord::Relation)
.to receive(:where).with(name: "...")
.and_return(user_double)
```

in your case, `where.not` is actually call `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain#not` method so i could do

```rb
allow_any_instance_of(ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain)
.to receive(:not).with(name: "Fred")
.and_return(user_double)
```